# Settings API settings section not appearing

Tags: theme-options, settings-api

Settings API always been a little confusing for me.

I am trying to add a simple theme options page for a child theme I am developing. I guess I am doing something wrong that preventing the section being appearing. The `settings_fields()` is working fine though (printing all those hidden fields in the form), but the sections are not. Here is my code, please help me troubleshooting.

```
/********************************
    Add Theme Sub Menu Page
********************************/
function sr_theme_options_setup() {
    add_theme_page( 'Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'edit_theme_options', 'srchild', 'ia_theme_page_settings' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'sr_theme_options_setup' );


/*************************************
    Generate Options Page HTML
*************************************/
function ia_theme_page_settings() {
?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php screen_icon('themes'); ?> <h2>Theme Settings</h2>
        <?php settings_errors( 'ia-settings-errors' ); ?>
        <form id="form-ia-options" action="options.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <?php
                    settings_fields('ia_options');
                    do_settings_sections('ia_section_id');
                ?>

                <p class="submit">
                    <input name="ia_options[submit]" id="submit_options_form" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Settings', 'iathemes'); ?>" />
                    <input name="ia_options[reset]" type="submit" class="button-secondary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Reset Defaults', 'iathemes'); ?>" />
                </p>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
}


/******************************************
    Register Settings/Section/Fields
******************************************/
function iathemes_init() {
    register_setting( 'ia_options', 'ia_options', 'ia_options_validate' );

    // Add a form section for the Logo
    add_settings_section('ia_section_id', __( 'Theme Settings', 'iathemes' ), 'ia_section_callback', 'srchild');

    // Add Logo uploader
    add_settings_field('ia_options_logo',  __( 'Logo', 'iathemes' ), 'ia_options_logo', 'srchild', 'ia_section_id');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'iathemes_init' );

function ia_section_callback() {
    ?>
        <p><?php echo 'Manage Theme Settings'; ?></p>
    <?php
}

function ia_options_logo() {
    $options = get_option( 'ia_options' );
    ?>
        <input type="text" id="logo_url" name="ia_options[site_logo]" value="<?php echo esc_url( $options['site_logo'] ); ?>" />
        <input id="upload_logo_button" type="button" class="button" value="<?php _e( 'Upload Logo', 'iathemes' ); ?>" />
        <span class="description"><?php _e('Upload an image for the banner. Should be 300x40 pixels in size', 'iatheme' ); ?></span>
    <?php
}
```

Please tell me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings API can be puzzling ;-)

Replace:

```
do_settings_sections( 'ia_section_id' );
```

with

```
do_settings_sections( 'srchild' );
```

to display your defined settings section.

The general usage is:

```
do_settings_sections( $page );
```

where:

> `$page` (string) (required) 
>   The slug name of the page whose settings
>   sections you want to output. This should match the page name used in
>   `add_settings_section()`. 
>   Default: None

according to the Codex ([here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_settings_sections)).

Comment: You're the man!! :)